# How to make a query to a table generated by a select?

Tags: sql, mysql

As an example:

```
SELECT name, address, phone FROM USER;
```

Generates the table

```
name | address | phone 
...  |   ...   |  ...
```

How can i use this table generated to make another query to it?

For example:

```
SELECT count(address) FROM (SELECT name, address, phone, from user);
```

I know it's not the best example, but is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a table in SQL? Do you want a new table in your database OR do you want an in-memory table to mess with?

Comment: i think the example of the select ... from (SELECT ... kinda explains it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same syntax but give your derived table an alias

```
SELECT count(subadd.address) 
FROM (SELECT name, address, phone, from user) as subadd;
```

Comment: Wouldn't "SELECT count(address) FROM user" yield the same result?

Comment: Absolutely, but I assumed the example was generic and the core question was how to handle the sub-query reference.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT name, address, phone FROM USER;
```

Then you can sue it as a table:

```
SELECT count(address) FROM my_view;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use temporary tables:

```
create temporary table t select name, address, phone;
select count(address) from t;
```

Few characteristics:
- the table will only be accessible by the current thread,
- the table will be dropped when the current thread will be finished
- creating such table requires appriopriate privileges

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using temporary tables.  I'd probably go with creating a view.  However, I'd run an explain to see what is faster if speed is needed.